# How to view results from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllAnnouncements]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Description, DisplayStartDate, DisplayEndDate 
    FROM
        Announcements
END
```

I am trying to call the stored procedure and return it as array, but I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly Convert Type MyProject.Models.GetAllAnnouncements_Result[] to string[]

My code:

```
public string[] getAllAnnouncements()
{
    using (PerformanceReviewEntities objContext = new PerformanceReviewEntities())
    {
        var ann =  objContext.GetAllAnnouncements();
        string[] DisplayAnn = ann.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I know it has to do something within the edit function import, but I am just not sure what to do. I want to be able to run from home controller, and view it in my .cshtml page.

[image]

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).  It comes with the SQL Server and has an explorer which you can view the Database tables and stored procedures.

Comment: The message says that the result is not a string array. It is an array of `GetAllAnnouncements_Result`. Think about what the procedure returns, can an object with 3 properties (Description, DisplayStartDate, DisplayEndDate) be a string?

Answer (score 1):

The function import is returning a collection of objects of type `Announcements`.

When you call this:

```
var ann =  objContext.GetAllAnnouncements();
```

`ann` is a collection of objects, not strings.

Doing this:

```
string[] DisplayAnn = ann.ToArray();
```

Wil fail because you are trying to assign an array of objects to an array of strings.

You could do this instead, assuming you are interested in more than one column:

```
IEnumerable<Announcements> result = ann.ToArray();
```

And change the signature of your method to return the enumerable:

```
public IEnumerable<Announcements> getAllAnnouncements()
```

The call to ToArray() is done to force loading of the results. You don't have to cast it to an array if lazing loading is fine for you. Some people have trouble with that when they try to consume the enumeration after the connection to the database has been closed (e.g. the context is disposed).

Comment: Hi thanks for feedback, I want to return description , start and end dates. Those three columns

Comment: Then why are you trying to cast it to an array of strings? I will update my answer to reflect your needs.

Comment: yeah I know its wrong, I just don't know how to retrieve all rows.

Comment: @Fenx: Read my answer one more time. I updated it to fit your requirements.